# Elements before FlatList are fixed on a page and doesn't scroll with FlatList

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist element and another element before flatlist. When I scroll up, the element before flatlist doesn't go up and is fixed. Is there a way to make it go up when faltlist is scrolled up?

Example:

```
  render() {
    return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<View>THIS ELEMENT BEFORE CONTAINER STAYS FIXED WHEN SCROLLING FLATLIST</View>
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.data}
        extraData={this.state}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
<View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's going to be much easier for people to help if you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Cheers!

Comment: @RichChurcher I updated it with example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I do understand you correctly you want to have your view on top be a part of the scrollable area of your `FlatList`. So you may want to make the view on top the `ListHeaderComponent`

```
 renderListHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Foo</Text>
      </View>
     );
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <FlatList
       data={this.props.data}
       extraData={this.state}
       keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
       renderItem={this._renderItem}
       ListHeaderComponent={this.renderListHeader}
     />
   );
}
```

Comment: is there any way to add a separate style to the header, because the header renders inside flatlist's container.

Comment: Well, you can use the style prop for the elements in your Header of cause. If this does not answer your question please provide an example of a desired result.

Comment: Hey, this is a link https://ibb.co/8Mrwyn2 I have already tried many things but i am completely stuck.

Comment: So, you want the Header to Scroll with the content of the FlatList and wrap your children in a box with rounded borders? Is that correct? Maybe you can add this borders to the first and last child rendered by renderItem? Or maybe „start“ and „end“ this rounded border box in ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent. Still not sure if I got your problem.

Comment: So, you want the Header to Scroll with the content of the FlatList and wrap your children in a box with rounded borders? Yes exactly, do you have any code examples? Because i have tried styling the header component but it is still rendered inside flatlist container.

Comment: LisHeaderComponent is Part of the FlatList. You can render it before the FlatList but than it won’t be part of the scrollable area. But here is an Illustration of my previous suggestion: https://ibb.co/RHnXwj3

Comment: Of cause you can also render the border radius in the first and last item of your list.

Comment: Man you are a lifesaver! That trick did the job! Thank you so much!